# If an electron moves closer to the nucleus in a given value of n, does it lose energy?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, electrons

If you look at a radial probability chart for a given electron sublevel (excluding n=1), there is a probability of an electron in that sublevel being closer to the nucleus. The electron should lose energy if it is closer to the nucleus because it experiences a greater force of attraction to the nucleus, but how is this possible if all electrons in a given sublevel have the same energy?

Comment: Stop thinking of probability as probability. An electron is not here or there; it is everywhere at once.

Comment: No, it doesn't. If you believe in electron orbits imagine it to be elliptical like in B-S model.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to apply macroscopic understanding to the world of quantum mechanics. This thinking is doomed to fail. The energy of an electron occupying a specific orbital is that orbital’s energy. Full stop. Unless it changes its orbital it does not change energy.

Comment: The electron does not occupy the orbital, it IS the orbital!